# Apache mod_rewrite %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} not equal + or condition (list)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My current condition is like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
```

I wonder how can I swap this condition into `if not` one of the values above.

I tought about something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !="android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you've got a space between `opera` and `mobile`, which causes mod_rewrite to parse it as multiple parameters. Try using parentheses instead of quotes in conjunction with `!` and escape the space:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close you don't need to add `=` after the negation `!`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
```