# .htaccess Separate www to non-www Redirects for Desktop and Mobile Websites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website which exists in both a desktop and mobile version, eg:

example.com
m.example.com

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This does a www to non-www redirection for desktop users (eg. www.example.com -> example.com).

I need a .htaccess code that will do a www to non-www redirection for mobile users (eg. www.m.example.com -> m.example.com) while not affecting the desktop redirection. What would be the correct code to use?

BTW The third line is there as it seems to let me access mobile pages using m.example.com instead of being redirected to example.com/m (because of the fourth line).

Answer (score 1):

Event though this is a bit off topic for stackoverflow, what you are after is using `HTTP_USER_AGENT`in your `RewriteCond`. There are a number of these questions on SO, but you could start at this one:

[mod_rewrite %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} not equal + or condition (list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138856/mod-rewrite-http-user-agent-not-equal-or-condition-list)

Also, reading the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page is a good start as a new user. :-)

Comment: I have already read the About page prior to posting and I am unsure as to how my question is off topic. If there is something painfully obvious I'm missing I'd appreciate if you could point it out so I know better for next time. 

As to the suggestion you offered - thanks - I checked out the link and the related links that appeared but I'm under the impression you're pointing me toward some kind of mobile detect function? I'm just looking for a rewrite command that works on a subdomain (eg. m.example.com) but doesn't interfere with the rewrite set for the main domain.

Comment: @Simon I stand corrected, `.htaccess` files are not off topic for SO as I first though. Regarding the other part of the comment I got the impression you wanted to direct mobile clients to your mobile site, hence needed a rule that would detect mobile clients. Once you did that you can pretty much reuse what you have with minor changes.