# Three clauses in a .htaccess - https&http, www&non-www, and IE 6-8

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get a .htaccess working on my site with a new SSL setup/certificate. It is working partially, but I can't seem to combine all the rules that I'm after. In plain english, the behaviour I am looking for is:

1. If the browser is IE 6-8, send the user to http. This includes
   sending all https requests to http. Additionally, send all non-www
   to www. Basically, if it is IE 6-8, send it to http/www.
2. If the browser is anything else, and http is requested, send to
   http. Again, send all non-www to www. Basically - any http request =
   http/www served
3. If the browser is anything else and https is requested, send to
   https. Again, send all non-www to www. Basically, any https
   requested = https/www served

At the moment I have:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect all http MSIE 6-8
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect all https MSIE 6-8
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Send http to http, non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Send https to https, non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything seems to be working, except https/www requests on IE 6-8 are still being served as https. What am I missing?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138856/mod-rewrite-http-user-agent-not-equal-or-condition-list) that parentheses seem to be required for the {HTTP_USER_AGENT} string, rather than the quotes I was using previously. I also introduced some negation in the first few rules. Probably there is a more elegant way to achieve the final result, but the rule set below seems to work for me.

```
RewriteEngine on

#Send http to http, non-www to www, checking that USER_AGENT isn't IE 6-8
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(MSIE\ [6-8]) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Send https to https, non-www to www, checking that USER_AGENT isn't IE 6-8
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(MSIE\ [6-8]) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect all http, MSIE 6-8, non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (MSIE\ [6-8]) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect all https, MSIE 6-8, non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (MSIE\ [6-8]) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect all https MSIE 6-8, www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (MSIE\ [6-8]) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```